# Leak in Icarousel memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, icarousel

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/downloads

[image]

There is a memory leak for iCarousel how to resolve the issue.

I am using this in my application. so i need to resolve the memory issue [leak's] while using the iCarousel.

Comment: You need some stronger arguments that this leak you're seeing is caused by iCarousel. What makes you think that class is to blame?

Comment: I am not blame the class..... Its great work which has been implemented i like it very much when i download this in separate folder and checking the application i got this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience before leak testing make sure “call tree” options is selected as well as for better result set Sampling option  to 5.0 sec.
Actually in the testing we mostly concentrate open only those leaks which 
Is generated within our code. So that’s why select “Show   Obj-C Only” option from Call tree.
Follow these steps:

```
➢   Activate call tree block.(Choose Call Tree option from drop down menu on the clicking on Leaked Blocks option) 
➢   Choose “Hide Missing Symbols” , “Hide System Libraries” and “Show Obj-C Only” option.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use many programs for debugging. for example, try Deleaker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with the plugin developers:

Pull a request there : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/pulls

See : [image]

You have better chances over there to find about your issue and i believe they will be interested with your case if iCarousel in involved .. if there is a case.